Headroom of CS Amplifier with Diode Connected Load
After reading books and simulating the below circuit, the maximum possible value of Vout, is VDD - VTH2. Is there any way, to increase this max vout value to get a larger output swing? Also, Ideally, Vout = VDD - VTH2 until Vin exceeds VTH1. But in this case, Vout decreases when Vin < VTH1, meaning there is some conduction in MN1. But is about 0.3V drop normal?


